# Cython: Converting a Cython function with `except` into C like function

Tags: python, c, cython

I am basically trying to wrap a C library and want to pass Python functions in wrapped C functions using Cython. I am using global variables to store the Python function, calling it in a Cython wrapper and then passing the Cython wrapper as a C function to some other C function. I want to capture the errors in the Python function when called by the Cython wrapper, so, I add a `except? -1` at the end of the Cython wrapper declaration.

The problem is when I pass a Cython function with `except` keyword, it fails to convert it into C like function. If I don't, I can't handle errors occuring in the Python function (I need to do this as the function is called in a loop)

A MRE is shown below.

```py
# file: mre.pyx

# cython: language_level=3

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

_glob_params = None
_glob_func = None

cdef extern from "mre.h":
    double eval_func(double (*func)(double, double *, int))

cdef double _func_wrapper(double x, double *params, int n) except? -1:
    return _glob_func(x, *_glob_params)

def run_func(func, params=(), Py_ssize_t size=100):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] out = np.empty(size, dtype=np.float64)
    global _glob_func, _glob_params

    _glob_func = func
    _glob_params = params

    for i in range(size):
        out[i] = eval_func(_func_wrapper)

    return out
```

```c
// file : mre.h

#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double eval_func(double (*func)(double, double *, int)) {
    double res = func(1.0, NULL, 0);
    if ( res < 0. ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: func < 0. -> not allowed!\n");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    _glob_func = func
    _glob_params = params

    for i in range(size):
        out[i] = eval_func(_func_wrapper)
                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

mre.pyx:24:27: Cannot assign type 'double (double, double *, int) except? -1.0' to 'double (*)(double, double *, int)'
```

Without `except? -1`:

```py
>>> from mre import run_func
>>> run_func(None)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: 'mre._func_wrapper'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception ignored in: 'mre._func_wrapper'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
             ...
             ...
             ...
             ...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

So, is there a way to handle exceptions in Cython without `except`? I tried to use `ctypes` to wrap the Python function but it is very slow in practice.

Comment: I think you need to take in the function address: `out[i] = eval_func(&_func_wrapper)`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I think functions are already pointers in C. So, you don't need to pass an explicit reference.

Comment: Ok, looking at `_glob_func(x, *_glob_params)` in _func_wrapper: _glob_func is None, so you are trying to call None, which explains "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: I am actually trying to demonstrate the long (the same error occurs a 100 times as the exception throw by Python is never captured) and unhelpful error I get when I don't do exception handling myself. I have passed `None` to the `run_func` function which is why I see the error. If I were to pass a actual function, it would get assigned to the `_glob_func` and would work. But what if an exception has occured in there? I want to capture that and that is why I am putting `except? -1` at the end of the wrapper. It doesn't work as Cython is not able to convert that signature into C compatible one.

Comment: So you want to propagate the error to eval_func? Maybe, in `cdef extern from "mre.h"` try adding `except? -1` to the declaration of the eval_func function.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but no luck. I think the C function needs to be changed to handle Python errors to do that. The problem is that the Python function is called from inside of C where it has no idea what Python error is... and I am not allowed to change the C source code.

Comment: Ok. After experimenting, I am able to throw the error only once.  I threw this error by modifying the eval_func in mre.h to use throw std::runtime_error.  Then, declare eval_func with "except +" in mre.pyx. I compile mre.pyx to c++ instead of c. The new error  thrown by c++ is caught in python with message "RuntimeError: ERROR: func < 0. -> not allowed!". This happens once. Is this what you want? I can write a full answer.

Comment: To clarify, I am making it throw once in a way that it can be handled in Python, as opposed to where you are having the same error occur 100 times but is never captured.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, @GoldenRockefeller. Unfortunately, I can't use C++ and also don't want to touch the C code too much :p. I will try to see if I could achieve similar results in C. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The way exceptions work in Python, once an exception is handled, the global stay must be changed, i.e. error must be cleared (e.g. via [`PyErr_Clear()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Clear)), otherwise the interpreter is in an inconsistent state and strange things can happen.

Because your C code is not aware of Python, it cannot clear the error indicator, thus it must happen in Cython code. One possibility would be to add an additional wrapper:

```
cdef double wrapper_noraise(double x, double *params, int n):
    try:
        return _func_wrapper(val)
    except:
        return -1.0
```

and now pass `wrapper_noraise` to C code.

Or, in your case,  you could directly change `_func_wrapper` to:

```
cdef double _func_wrapper(double x, double *params, int n):
    try:
       return _glob_func(x, *_glob_params)
    except:
       return -1.0
```

Comment: So instead of cython ignoring the exception, this will manually handle it? Is it possible to have the exception propagated to Python?

Comment: @GoldenRockefeller In OP's version, Cython doesn't ignore the exception - it aborts the execution of the function but doesn't clear the error-indicator, thus the caller of the function gets notified, that an error has occurred and reacts accordingly. However, because the caller of the throwing function is C-code which knows nothing about Python exceptions, the only way to ensure that python-interpreter will not be in an inconsistent state is to clear the error indicator and to transform it to an error which is understood by the C-code (i.e. result <0.0).

Comment: @GoldenRockefeller If you want to have a sustainable way to propagate error back to Python, there should be a way to know that there was an error in the C-code (right now this is the error message to stderr - not really convenient, but possible to use) and then to detect this state and raise Python exception after the C-code was executed.

Comment: To clarify, I meant "ignoring exception" in reference to the output in OP's answer saying "Exception ignored in: 'mre._func_wrapper'" instead of stopping the program. I think the reason that this message is repeated is because the Python's error-indicator is being cleared. Almost like, after printing this message, the code is pretending the error didn't happen.

Comment: @GoldenRockefeller Ok I undestand now. Yes, Cython does that check, but in between the interpreter is in a inconsistent state. One might get lucky and nothing happens in between, but one might also get unlucky and C-code could call another Python-code which would do strange things because of this.

Comment: Thanks! This does allow me to get rid of repeating error messages but not handle them. Considering the C code knows nothing about Python exceptions, it seems unlikely there is a good way to do this. Even though this doesn't answer my question, I think this is the closest we can get. (Turns out, the C library I was using has a error code global variable which is set on error. I can access it from Cython and handle the error easily.)